# How to use multi-threading to call number of services?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on currency card website which shows dashboard once user logs in.
Dashboard consists of following sections:
(1) Transaction Details of card holder. (Grid with transaction details) 
(2) Currencies available in my purse(card).
(3) Currency to currency conversion rates. 
(4) Reward points against my card.

Now, all these 4 points have service written for that which my business logic (Java class) file calls.

Now, here I can make use of multithreading to make the performance of my dashboard page good. I want to call all these services asynchronously so that my page will loaded faster.

Can you guys please suggest me topics to search on google to achieve my above functionality.

P.S : I want to achieve above functionality in Java not in any JS framework (as per requirement)

Comment: Well, have a look at asynchronous javascript requests. Load your page and then issue those requests to fetch the dashboard data.

Comment: No not javascript, I want to achieve this in Java as I am writing down a API.

Comment: The question you asked here is very subjective and something that requires a discussion about the overall architecture, framework and cannot be answered. There are lots of java based framework some quite widely adopted (spring-boot) and others less and you need to decide one that you wish to use and comfortable with. Most of those frameworks use concurrency under the hood. Please provide some code snippet that shows your current implementation so that some help can be extended.

Comment: I am in architectural level discussion. Requirement is to utilize the multithreading here.

Comment: Well, you _could_ use multiple threads to gather the data needed to display your dashboard but there'd still be one single thread that actually builds the response. And as piy26 pointed out we lack a lot of information on your architecture, requirements (e.g. why no client-side JS?) etc.

Comment: "Requirement is to utilize the multithreading here." - Why? If you want your page to load really fast you'll need to use client-side JS to load the data asynchronously (and maybe poll for updates or use websocket for push messages, which would require JS to update the page as well).

Answer (score 0):

Considering that each of your 4 sections has a different service call, you may utilize [ExecutorService#invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) to concurrently execute all service calls and then consolidating the result as per your need.